# SQL Aggregate Functions with Subqueries

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have these two tables:

**public.country**

| Column | Type | Collation | Nullable | Default |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name | text |  | not null |  |
| two_letter | text |  | not null |  |
| country_id | integer |  | not null |  |

- *Indexes:*

  ```
   "country_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (two_letter)
  ```

**public.subcountry**

| Column | Type | Collation | Nullable | Default |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| country | text |  | not null |  |
| subcountry_name | text |  | not null |  |
| subdivision | text |  |  |  |
| subcountry_level | text |  |  |  |

- *Indexes:*

  ```
  "subcountry_country_subcountry_name_key" 
       UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (country, subcountry_name)
  ```
- *Foreign-key constraints:*

  ```
  "subcountry_country_fkey" 
       FOREIGN KEY (country) REFERENCES country(two_letter)
  ```

I want to find the average number of subcountries that countries whose `two_letter' starts with the letters "A" and "Z" have. I want the output to be like this:

```
PREFIX | Subcountry Average
-------+-------------------
 A     |        some_number
 Z     |        some_number
```

The output above is, according to my understanding, achievable by using `GROUP BY`. I know the way to go is to count all `subcountry` that the `two_letter` that starts with the specified letter has and divide it by the amount of that `two_letter`s. Here is my attempt for the `two_letter`s that start with the letter A:

```
SELECT COUNT(countryA) AS countryAsum
FROM (
    SELECT country.name AS countryA
    FROM country
    WHERE country.two_letter LIKE 'A_'
) a;
-- result: 16

SELECT COUNT(subcountryA) as countryAsubcountrySum
FROM (
    SELECT subcountry.country AS subcountryA
    FROM subcountry, country
    WHERE country.two_letter LIKE 'A_' AND country.two_letter = subcountry.country
) a;
-- result: 232

-- hence, the wanted output is: 232 / 16 = 14.5
```

Now, I only need to divide `countryAsubcountrySum` by `countryAsum` and make it one query only. The problem is, I don't know how. And not only that, I also have to make this a single query for `two_letter`s that start with the letter Z. Any help would be appreciated. (and pardon my bad English)

Comment: Could you please provide an example of your data and expected output?

Comment: You need to have a column which is common to the 2 sub-queries to be able to join them. Either country name or 2 letter code, but the same in both.